# Calling the same function a second time causes error in a class

Tags: python-3.x, class

So for some reason when I call function the first time around, it creates the requested number of agents but when I use it a second time(within another function, time_skip function), this gets me an error. I've been stuck on this for some time and I can't seem to find answers anywhere. The error occurs when the code goes through the Create_agents function, but ONLY the second time.

```
class agent(object):
    def __init__(self, identification, age):
        self.identification = identification
        self.age = age
    def description(self):
        print("My id is", self.identification)
        print("My age is", self.age)


def Create_agents():
    global id
    list.append(agent(id,28 ))
    id += 1
    
# functions
def Initialize():
    for x in range(3):
        Create_agents()
         
def Time_skip():
    global year
    year += 1
    print("The new year is", year)
    for agent in list:
        agent.age +=1
    Create_agents()
    
        
# Values
list = []
id = 0
year = 0
Initialize()

# Testing
for agent in list: 
    agent.description()
    
Time_skip()

for agent in list: 
    agent.description()
```

The complete output is:

```
My id is 0
My age is 28
My id is 1
My age is 28
My id is 2
My age is 28
The new year is 1

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-4f7c476091fc> in <module>
     37     agent.description()
     38 
---> 39 Time_skip()
     40 
     41 for agent in list:

<ipython-input-76-4f7c476091fc> in Time_skip()
     24     for agent in list:
     25         agent.age +=1
---> 26     Create_agents()
     27 
     28 

<ipython-input-76-4f7c476091fc> in Create_agents()
     10 def Create_agents():
     11     global id
---> 12     list.append(agent(id,28 ))
     13     id += 1
     14 

TypeError: 'agent' object is not callable
```

Comment: Your code has a lot of bad practice like mutating global state, non-standard naming conventions, and shadowing. You might want to post on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are overwriting the name of your class `agent` in this for loop:

```
for agent in list: 
    agent.description()
```

Change your class name to `Agent` and you will see the error is gone. This is why we should always follow some naming conventions, like mentioned in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

Edit:

I just realized that you are also overwriting the built-in function `list`. This is what they call killing two birds with one stone ******.

****** I know it is overwritten earlier but whatever, it needs to be changed :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is caused by the fact that when you call `Initialize()`, `agent()` calls the constructor of the class, but when you call `Time_skip()`, `agent` is an instance of the object after you ran:

```
for agent in list: 
    agent.description()
```

In this piece change `agent` to `item` or something else. Error will go away.